# I can hide or delete comment date on blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a problem I try to hide date comment on my blog but didn't work can someone help please

[image: Image Site]

[image: Editor Image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, this question as asked is unlikely to garner much attention from the community.  I would recommend reviewing [ask] and trying again.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a piece of code of what you tried ?

Because hiding and showing HTML elements is not a very hard thing to do, so it could be the placing of the hide/show statement or it could be the syntax.

It is difficult to tell what is happening without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

On Blogger. To hide data comment you need to target the element `.datetime`

Because there is already a display attribute specified to `.datetime.secondary-text` in your snipped code, You can change this attribute from `display: inline-block` to `display: none` or use the following CSS rule to override the existing one.

```
.comment .datetime.secondary-text { display: none }
```